# How can I access the Coordinates constructor directly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, vue.js, w3c-geolocation

Type checking in Vue requires the constructor function to be passed in as the type:

```
props: {
  coords: {
    type: Coordinates,
    required: true,
  },
},
```

I can't work out how to find the `Coordinates` constructor. Can't use `Object` because it doesn't inherit from anything, and would prefer not to just allow anything.

There's nothing on MDN about how to access it directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates

Any ideas?

EDIT: To clarify, `window.Coordinates` is undefined. The above code example doesn't work.

Comment: mdn says it's an interface, so try to find its implementation's prototype maybe?

Comment: @潘俊杰: That's what I was asking. I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Coordinates` is **not** something exposed in the browser to be used by web developers. It's an interface defined by W3C geo specs, for **browser vendors** who implement the geolocation features. An interface describes how a certain type of data structure looks like. For example, `coords` in the following example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
  var coords = pos.coords
  console.log(coords)
})
```

Even though you could retrieve the literal of `Coordinates` with following code. It's just an object (yes, it's prototype, not constructor), you can barely do anything.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(pos.coords)
```

So two points here:

1. `Coordinates` is not for web developers.
2. `Coordinates` is not even a function.

The only way I guess, is to [define your own validator](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation) and check whether the input value meets your requirement. This would be easier because `Coordinates` has a special `toString()` symbol:

```
props: {
  coords: {
    validator: function (value) {
      return value.toString() === '[object Coordinates]'
    }
  }
}
```

However, this validator may fail if you hand-craft your own coords data. A more generic way is like duck-typing, just check whether it has proper properties you need, `latitude` and `longitude` usually.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the value is an intance of your contructor, using a custom validator:

```
coords {
  validator: function (value) {
      return value instanceOf Coordinates; // Coordinates is a constructor in your case
  }
}
```

Take a look of [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) Documentation.

Comment: I know how to use `instanceof`. `window.Coordinates` is undefined.

Comment: You can make your own validator for coordinates or create your own class/prototype

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with this problem too. My solution is **define a fake constructor**:

```
function Coordinates () {}
Coordinates.prototype = Object.prototype
```

in vue component

```
props: {
  coords: {
    type: Coordinates
  }
}
```

This will work because Vue use `instanceof` to validate custom types.

Comment: This defeats the point in using the validation: you might as well use `type: Object`.

Comment: @callumacrae : Vue validate `type: Object` using `Object.prototype.toString.call(propValue) === '[object Object]'`，so you can NOT use `type: Object` to validate any object with constructor